# Are minor Upaniṣads Shruti?

Tags: upanishads, classification

Upaniṣads like Maha Upaniṣad [*linked with Samaveda*], Narayana Upaniṣad [*linked with Krishna Yajurveda*] and Tejobindu Upaniṣad [*linked with Yajurveda*] all are minor Upaniṣads.

So are they (minor Upaniṣad) Shruti or Smriti?

Comment: This is a really good question, I hope we get good answers on it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All the 108 upanishads contained in the list of Muktika upanishad are considered to be shruti. The complete text of muktika upanishad [is here](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_upanishhat/muktika.itx) and the [translation is here](http://www.vedarahasya.net/muktika.htm). All the three above upanishads are listed there as numbers 61, 18, 37.

SrI VidyAraNya svAmI cites Muktika Upanishad (MuktikopaniSat) in PanchdaSI 4.68 and thus says all the upanishads cited therein must be shruti.

Comment: "All the 108 upanishads contained in the list of Muktika upanishad are considered to be shruti." Can you add reference for this point as this is crucial point in your answer?

Comment: I checked Vidyāraṇya's  Pañcadaśi 4.68, there is a citation of Muktikā Upaniṣada in 4.68 but he doesn't say that it is śruti. So, the answer is just not satisfactory. 
If you think I checked wrong, I will share the book link https://estudantedavedanta.net/Panchadashi_Vidyaranya_Swahananda.pdf
Just because Vidyāraṇya cites a text doesn't imply that it becomes śruti and in the first place, he doesn't say anything that it is śruti or not.

Comment: @TheDestroyer I checked what GIRIBLR cited, but that doesn't support his/her point at all. It's a surprise as to how this answer got votes because the reason he/she gave for all 108 Upaniṣads to be śruti is not valid.