# Are all Upanishads shruti?

Tags: vedas, upanishads, smriti, shruti

Are all 108 Upanishads considered shruti? Or is it just the Mukhya Upanishads that are considered shruti?

Comment: Does this ans. your question https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/45730/are-minor-upani%e1%b9%a3ads-shruti/45732#45732

Comment: @Athrey Are you saying that even the medieval era Upanishads are shruti?

Comment: Not sure what characterstics become a factor to be called , that it belongs to medival era, etc. The answer in the link says that, just because a portion of Muktikopanishad is quoted  in Panchdashi , the authenticity of it should not be suspected. Consequently the list of upanishads occuring in Muktikopanishad, are deemed to be shruti, bcos swami Vidyaranya has ack. the same.Hence only thru a commentary or a quote by a seer, it possible to discover / interpret .

Comment: I don't consider minor Upaniṣads to be śruti. I am no authority to say that. But mukhya upaniṣads have a special status among the 108 upaniṣads of muktikā canon. 
@Athrey And that link doesn't answer the question properly at all. You can check my comment on that answer. Just by citing a minor Upaniṣad doesn't prove that it and all other Upaniṣads are śruti.

Comment: @Bingming , Discounting Muktikopanishad,  other sources that contain list of 108 upanishads , are not known . Authenticity of Muktikopanishad is not in question, as it is cited by Swami Vidyaranya(as per ans.).Also some of the minor upanishads are authentic, as they appear in commentary of seers. Sometimes their association with other portions such as brahmana ,aranyaka , and also the nature of shanthi mantra may give a cue about the upanishad, afaik.Veda mantras are forsaken overtime., Those  mantras that are beheld by the lineage, is what is known for sure.

Comment: @Athrey Perhaps, you didn't understand what I meant. I never said that the minor Upaniṣads are unauthentic. No one says they are unauthentic. Even the Purāṇas, dharmaśāstras etc. are smr̥ti that doesn't mean they are not authentic. I am just clarifying that only because a minor Upaniṣad has been cited by some ācāryas isn't a justification for that Upaniṣad for being śruti. Even Manusmr̥ti is cited by some ācāryas in the Brahmasūtra bhāṣya, that doesn't make this dharmaśāstra a śruti.
And ślokas from Purāṇas are also often cited in the bhāṣyas too, that doesn't make the Purāṇa  śruti.

Comment: Citation by an ācārya is not the determiner of calling the cited text as śruti. If it was, many so-called smr̥ti texts would qualify as śruti. I can give another example, that of the citation of Jaimini sūtras in Brahmasūtra and its bhaṣya. Everyone knows that citation or reference doesn't make it śruti. And if you are saying about the association with the Veda, then each of the 108 Upaniṣads have actually been associated with the four Vedas. This is again not a determiner for śruti, for this association of each is pretty late.

Comment: And there are some Upaniṣads, which are actually of śākhās but not in the Muktikā canon of 108 Upaniṣads. For e.g. Bāṣkala Upaniṣad, and that is from the Bāṣkala śākha of the R̥g Veda.

Comment: @Bingming , It is said that  *Ananta vai Vedaha* (vedas are infinite) .So what is the basis, to affirm a certain upanishad as Shruti?

Comment: @Athrey You are just sidestepping when your logic of determining śruti was falsified. The question wasn't about the basis of determination (and as to why we should do so). It was about determination (please don't forget the question put by the OP).  And I am not affirming anything here. With proper logic, I showed the problem in your argument before. Thanks for the conversation, anyway. I hope I was clear in the above explanation to you.